# How are real-time notification systems made in Nodejs?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, notifications, mean, publish-subscribe

I want to create a social-media website project for my peronsal portfolio. But, I am really confused about how to develop a notification system.

If user-A likes a post of user-B, user-B should be instantly notified. Once he opens it, the notification will be read. Sometimes, even multiple users need to get the same notification. How is this achieved? Not talking about some 3rd-party tool but how the architecture works and if there iss any way to efficiently implement this is Node.js.

I do not want user-B to keep hitting any API for checking. I want the data to come instantly as it does in Facebook, or even in Stack Overflow. Any solution?

I am using MEAN stack.

Comment: The question is too open. Start studying websockets

Comment: I want to know about different avenues of achieving this. Websocket is one. Are there any more?